# how to show group of images in android

Tags: android, image

I'm playing with images in android. I'm using 5 images in my app and I want that these images look something like this
[image]

I think I can do this but It is taking lots of rams and I'm also unable to implement a sliding animation when I slide images.
Is there anyway so I get this result.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this [library](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow) and achieved the same result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there lib for this case, however, I thought that you see libs that  working with images like http://frescolib.org/, https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView, you find one solution for you or inspire you to create yourself.